# Swift iOS: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, swift

In my main ViewController, I have this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    println("VIEW CONTROLLER DID APPEAR")

    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    println(currentUser)

    if (!currentUser) {
        self.presentLogInController()
    } else {
        println("VALID USER")
    }
}
```

When I run the app, this line throws an error:

```
if (!currentUser) {
```

saying EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

However, the output window shows:

```
VIEW CONTROLLER DID APPEAR
<PFUser:TzzzzzzaHx:(null)> {
    email = "blah@blah.bla";
    username = mmm;
}
VALID USER
```

Given that the code executes beyond the line XCode says is causing the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION, it doesn't seem like a critical error, though it causes the simulator & real device to crash.

Any advice on how to debug this?

**FOUND A SOLUTION**

```
if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
    println("VALID USER")
    println(user)
    println(user["email"])
    println(user["completedTour"])
    if !user["completedTour"] {
        println("NO TOUR YET")
    }
} else {
    self.presentLogInController()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are treating a swift problem like it's objective-c. Since, PFUser.currentUser() returns either a PFUser or nil, it will have to be contained in an optional variable.

```
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
```

Then you can check if the optional contains a value using an if statement.

```
if currentUser {
    println("VALID USER")  
} else {
    self.presentLogInController()
}
```

If you want to use the value of currentUser inside the if block, you should use an if let statement instead. `if let user = currentUser {...}` It will unwrap the optional if it has a value so you can deal with the value itself.

Comment: Same error at this line: var currentUser: PFUser? = PFUser.currentUser()

Comment: var currentUser: PFUser? = PFUser.currentUser()

Comment: hm perhaps `if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() as PFUser`

Comment: "Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type"

Comment: if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() as PFUser? {     fails with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: put the question mark on the as: `if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() as? PFUser`

Comment: adding the ? after the as failed with "Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55469/discussion-between-connor-and-z-jones).

Answer (score 3):

`if (!currentUser)` ... is `currentUser` a `Bool`? Not likely. You cannot use non-Bool expressions in if statements like in Objective-C

Assuming `PFUser.currentUser()` returns an implicitly unwrapped optional you will need to check for nil.

`if currentUser != nil { ... }`

Comment: Optionals are valid as if-conditions. Per the docs: "If an optional does have a value, it evaluates to true; if it has no value at all, it evaluates to false."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However,     if (currentUser != nil) {      ... throws the same error

Comment: same error with:  if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {

Comment: Thanks for the reminder Chuck, that's the one exception that slipped my mind :)